# [MASM32, irvine32 library]Converting BYTE string separated by spaces to integer, am I doing it right?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, irvine32, masm32

Input is random number of integers(does not exceed 1 byte), separated with spaces like this : `-3 4 5 7 8 -1`

There is `ReadInt` function in Irvine32 library, as far as I know, one integer as its input function. But since there is no clear information about the number of inputs, I had to declare the space in BYTE string form like this :

```
keyListInString BYTE 31 DUP(0)
```

and get integer string like this :

```
mov edx,OFFSET keyListInString
mov ecx,SIZEOF keyListInString
call ReadString
```

and I tried to separate each integers by recognizing spaces,'-' symbol and manually inserting them to new space I have created.

```
keyListInInteger BYTE 31 DUP(0)    ;new space for integers
```

And here is the code I used.

```
    mov esi,OFFSET keyListInString
    mov edi,OFFSET keyListInInteger
    mov ecx,eax        ;eax = length of string = number of cycles
L1:
    mov al,[esi]
    cmp al,45        ;if current component of keyListInString is '-'
    je ifMinus

    mov al,[esi]
    cmp al,0        ;if this is null(space)
    je ifNull

    mov al,[esi]    ;if its none of above(normal number)
    sub al,48       ;sub 48 for ascii --> integer
    mov [edi],al    ;put integer to where edi points(keyListInInteger)
    inc edi
    jmp final

ifMinus:
    inc esi        ;points next index on keyListInString(number part)
    mov al,[esi]
    sub al,48
    neg al        ;have to reverse the sign, because it is originally a minus
    mov [edi],al
    inc edi        ;manually increase edi
    jmp final

ifNull:
    inc esi        ;it is space anyway, so point next.
    jmp L1         ;and repeat from first.

final:
    inc esi
    loop L1
```

I tried to check if this is the right code in this way :

```
   mov edx,OFFSET keyListInInteger
   mov al,[edx]    ;see [edx+2],[edx+4],...
   movzx eax,al
   call DumpRegs
```

and see `al`'s value.

I think I somehow approached to the result I wanted, but not exactly. 
I wanted to make each integers like elements in an array, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: `ebx` holds 4 bytes but characters are 1 byte. Use a 8 bit register.

Comment: @Jester Oh, right..I changed `ebx` to `al`, and modified cheking code. It seems like I get correct values when I increase `edx` by 2, but why?

Comment: Space is not 0, it's 32. Also if you want space for 31 integers that's 3 times as much in text form in the worst case (one additional byte for the `-` sign and one for the following space).